# Adding Lookup reference values in Yaml file

Tags: json, xml, dataweave, mulesoft

Input JSON is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

    [
        {
    
        "Master_Job__r": {
    
         "Description_of_Loss__c": "This is Raja",  
          "Date_of_Loss__c": "2020-06-08",
    
          "Id": null,
    
          "type": "Master_Job__c"
    
        },
    
        "Amount__c": null,
    
        "Job_Number__c": "C##-#7-00041",
    
        "Property_ID__r": {
    
          "Country__c": "United States",
    
          "City__c": "Chennai",
    
          "Zip__c": "77777",
    
          "Address_Line_1__c": "null Testa St",
    
          "Id": null,
    
          "type": "Home",
    
          "State__c": "CA",
          
          "phone__C": "948-125-6666",
          
          "Job_Number__C": "GSD-45613",
        
          "Phone_Ext__C": "257452",
        
          "TOL_Code__c": "EARTHQUAKE",
        
          "TOL_desc__c": "",
        
          "PolicyNum__c": "GSD-123654",
        
          "COvapplyTo__c": "0",
        
          "PolicyLim__c": "156",
        
          "PolDeduc__c": "1562",
        
          "Covname__c": "Rup",
        
          "CovType__c": "4",
        
          "id__c": "4586",
          
          "Date_Taken__c": "2020-08-16",
          
          "Email__c": "sfadmin@demandblue.com",
    
        },
               "Email__C": "rupesh@gmail.com",
     
       "Account_Roles__r": [
    
          {
    
            "Multiple_Roles__c": "Primary/Bill-to;Caller",
                "Id": null,
                "type": "Account_Roles__c",
                "Contact_ID__r": { 
              "Name": "Test QA"
                }
              },
              {
                "Multiple_Roles__c": "Project Site Contact",
                "type": "Account_Roles__c",
                "Contact_ID__r": {
                "Name": "Test DB Con002"
                }
              }
            ],
            "Id": null,
        "Project_Manager_Email__c": null
         }
    ]
```

Dataweave code in XML is

```
 %dw 2.0
    output application/xml 
    ---
    XACTDOC: {(payload map(object,index)->{
            ADM:{
           dateofloss @("Dateofloss":payload.Master_Job__r[0].Date_of_Loss__c as String,"dateReceived":payload.Property_ID__r[0].Date_Taken__c as String):""default""   
       },
        
        TOLcode: {
                "test": payload.Property_ID__r[0].TOL_Code__c as String,
            
            "Desc": p('Typeofloss.EARTHQUAKE')
        }
    })}
```

Output XML Format is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<XACTDOC>
  </ADM><Coverage_Loss><PolicyNumber PolNum="GSD-123654" claimNumber="GSD-45613"/>
  <TOLcode><test>EARTHQUAKE</test><Desc>Earthquake</Desc></TOLcode></XACTDOC>
```

And i have created and stored a Name value lookup in .YAML File like

```
Typeofloss: 
  EARTHQUAKE: "Earthquake"
  FIRE: "Fire"
  Flood: "Flood"
  FREEZE: "Freeze"
  VANDALISM: "Vandalism"
  ENVIRONMENT: "Environmental Remediation"
  STORM: "Hurrican/Tornado/Blizzard/Noreaster"
```

And now my requirement is if TOL_CODE "Test" field is "STORM" then i need "DESC" field as a "Hurrican/Tornado/Blizzard/Noreaster" as an Output.
I will get Input TOL_CODE values dynamically.
How can we get the lookup values in Dataweave expressions without entering manually.
i tried with this logic but it is not working.

"test": payload.Property_ID__r[0].TOL_Code__c as String,
"Desc": p('Typeofloss.'+payload.Property_ID__r[0].TOL_Code__c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `++` to concat strings for the Desc field i.e.

```
"Desc": p('Typeofloss.' ++ payload.Property_ID__r[0].TOL_Code__c)
```

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-plusplus#plusplus2

Comment: Hi Stevens,thx for the update its working fine.Suppose if the input field is in Numbers (1,2,4,) then as an output i require (<10000,10000-50000,50000-100000) But i tried adding this values in properties.YAML ENVIRONMENT: "Environmental Remediation"STORM: "Hurrican/Tornado/Blizzard/Noreaster"1 : "<10000"2 :"10000-50000" and i am using the same code as per u shared but it is throughing an error in dataweave Expression as org.mule.runtime.config.internal.dsl.model.config.ConfigurationPropertiesException: Couldn't read from file config.yaml I Would like to know is there any changes in YAML file

Comment: Hi can you please post this question with input/dw script/expected output to the `dataweave` channel... can't tell exactly what is being asked. Thx!